# Showing selected entities on a Leaflet map from onclick action within a <div>

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, css

I have displayed a layer of points using Leaflet. Here is my script embedded in the HTML code :

```
var map = L.map('map', {
                center: [45.7604276, 4.8335709],
                zoom: 13
                });
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: '© <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
$.getJSON("personnes.geojson", function(data_point){
L.geoJson(data_point).addTo(map);})
```

Outside the box of the map, I got some  sections that I would like to connect with my map e.g. show selected entities in a certain color on my Leaflet after an onclick action in my  box.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can do something like:

`document.getElementById("elementID").innerHTML = properties.GeoJSONField;
`
where "GeoJSONField" refers to the key in your GeoJSON layer whose values you want to add to the <div id="elementID"></div>

Comment: What have you tried so far and what does not work?

Comment: Question leaves more or less everything to guessing: What are these "some sections"? What are "selected entities"? What is "my box"? Please include all relevant code into body of the question.

Comment: I have some demos from a class up at http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/ the Panel Map or Panel Select Map may help.

Answer (score 0):

I got more or less what I was looking for. This command `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML` is very useful for my purpose.